# ArcGIS Online Interactive Legend filter features

Tags: arcgis-online

I am working on a sign inventory for an area. I really like the interactive legend web app thing. I am pretty new and still trying to wrap my head around everything. In a nutshell, I'm working off a single CSV file imported from an app called Fulcrum. Everything displays as I want it to. However, I'm looking to filter the results by two variables rather than just one variable as seen in this picture.

[image]

So let's just say in a hypothetical scenario, I want to see cycle infrastructure signs. But, I want to see the cycle infrastructure signs that also have pedestrian features in it. What way can I filter this where both of these layers work in tandem?

[image]

both of these layers I made come from the same CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

To symbolize a feature based upon two TEXT fields create the symbology in ArcGIS Pro then share the layer to AGOL.

[image: Create symbology]

*Setting layer to unique values using two fields*

Results are:

[image: Legend in AGOL]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ok, I understand. I don't have ArcGIS Desktop, but I have QGIS and can replicate this. How would I get the styles from QGIS to show in ArcGIS online?

Comment: You cannot, qgis cannot connect to arcgis online like that.